# Unable to select element when element is in span than select Selenium c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am trying to select an element from dropdown with text as Ad. My page has a telerik dropdown and this is the HTML Code.

[image]

I am running following code:

```c#
SelectElement IDdropdown = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(TrackingEnrityID_Dropdown));
IDdropdown.SelectByText("Ad");
```

and throws this runtime error:

> An exception of type
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException' occurred in
>   WebDriver.Support.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Element should have been select but was span

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the element you are working on is NOT embedded in a `select` tag, so you can't use `Select` class on that element. When you use a Select class,
a check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag. If it is not,
        then an `UnexpectedTagNameException` is thrown.

So, what you can do is:

1. Identify the locator for the element.
2. Perform a click on the element.
3. identify the locator for the element from the dropdown and click on the required element. You can't use any of the select class methods like `select_by_index` or by `select_by_visible_text` etc.